# ¿Cómo unir varias tablas MS Access desde VB.net en Visual Studio?

Tags: base-de-datos, vb.net, ms-access

estoy realizando un sistema de escritorio en visual studio con access, ¿como podría unir varias tablas con visual studio?

Estoy realizando un sistema de escritorio para el inventario de una farmacia y tengo dificultad para unir las tablas de Access con visual studio 2022, ¿Cómo lo podría realizar?

```
If txtID.Text = "0" Then
        Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("insert into productos(NomProducto,TipoProd,FVencimiento,precio,stock) values('" & txtProducto.Text & "','" & TextBox2.Text & "','" & TextBox1.Text & "','" & txtPrecio.Text & "','" & txtStock.Text & "')", Conexion)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! tu pregunta no tiene sentido.. a que te referis con unir tablas? cual es el problema que tuviste con ese codigo?